# MAPR -File Read and Write Process

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I am not able to find a specific link that explains to me how the meta data is distributed in MAPR(File meta data). When I look at cloudera / hortonworks /apache hadoop I know the meta data is stored in namenode's memory which is then fetched to locate the nodes that holds the blocks. How does it work in MAPR is what I am trying to understand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

MapR natively implemented a Network File System (NFS) interface to MapR-FS so that any reads and writes from and to a file system, whether it be to a local file system, Network Attached Storage, or a Storage Area Network, can read and write data from and to MapR-FS.

This is also the reason MapR asks for a raw disk during the installation so that, it reformats the disk as MapR-FS.

Just came across this thread :

http://answers.mapr.com/questions/108/how-is-metadata-stored.html

Comment: Thanks for your response , but i am still a bit confused. As per the note in the above link that you provided it says "All parts of the file system are accessible from the root of the filesystem. The basic mechanism for finding a root of the filesystem is similar in spirit to the way that the root of a conventional file system is found ... there are well known locations in the underlying storage mechanism that contain the information about where the root is" . i am confused how replication happen in MAPR and how file is read by a client.

Comment: @Garfield I'm a bit late to this party, but the comment you mention in your difficulty basically means "it works like a UNIX filesystem"  If you start from the root "maprfs:///" or "/" you can change directory below into any file until you hit a permissions problem.  Some of those sub-directories might take you into a different volume, but just like UNIX, you won't notice (in UNIX some of the directories take you into different disks, without you noticing).