# anatomy of a file read and write in MapR-FS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mapr

I am trying to understand what is the anatomy of a file read and write in MapR-FS? 
I googled a lot but did not get clear understanding what are the steps of file read and write in MapR-FS.

I also found this quetion [MAPR -File Read and Write Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803054/mapr-file-read-and-write-process) but did not get clear understaing.

I know in MapR there is no namenode, it has CLDB that stores the location of containers and metadata is stored in all datanode in containers.

It would be great help if someone can explain step by step how this process works.